# Need to make python and Drupal XML exchange

Tags: xml, python-2.7, drupal

i´m new using both Python and Drupal, so sorry if my question is something stupid.

Well what i need is to create a connection between python and drupal at my drupal xml server.

```
import xmlrpclib, pprint, urllib2
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
config = {
  'url': 'http://myserver.com/xmlrpc',
  'username': 'admin',
  'password': 'password',
}

server = xmlrpclib.Server(config['url'], allow_none=True);
connection = server.system.connect();
session = server.user.login(connection['sessid'], config['username'], config['password']);
sessid = session['sessid'];
user = session['user'];
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
```

After this i will create a new node and insert data but actually i cannot connect to my server.
error: [Errno 10060]

Comment: Do you receive some kind of error message?

Comment: Stefan i got error : [errno 10060] time out. Iam using XMLRPC Server and Drupal 7. thanks

Comment: What happens if you just try to load that URL in your browser? Does it deliver anything?

Comment: If i try directly from brownser it returns this:
XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.

Comment: Can you give us a little background about what you are trying to accomplish using the XML-RPC service?

Comment: I will use python to search the web for news and update my website. I want it to happen automatically so i think xml-rpc is the best way to do it. If you have a suggestion about it too, i will be glad.

Comment: The [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module might be a good solution for you. Your python script is already going to be retrieving and parsing the data. It would be easy to create an ATOM file that can be grabbed by the Feeds module on a regular basis. It can parse the atom feed and create/update nodes for you on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Quint i will have a look at it, if someone have an idea how to solve this xml-rpc problem please share !